# Angular 4 and Dashboard

Tags: angular, widget

I'm new with Angular 4 and I'm trying to create an App with a Dashboard.

User can choose what he want to see on the main dashboard.

In this App, I have to 4 directories : "Dashboard", "Clients", "Products" and "Sales"

Only the 3 last have some `service` and `module`.

Here is my architecture :

```
App
|
|__Clients
|__Dashboard
|__Products
|__Sales
```

If I go to : `/*/clients/` => App display informations about clients only

If I go to : `/*/products/` => App display informations about products only

If I go to : `/*/sales/` => App display informations about sales only

My question : what is the bests practices to display some widgets (clients + products + sales) on my main dashboard without copy/paste my code?

Answer (score 1):

try to import their services into the dashboard component and do what you need

```
import { ClientService } from './ClientServicePath';
import { ProductsService } from './ProductsServicePath';
import { SalesService } from './SalesServicePath';

constructor(
   private clientSer: ClientService,
   private productsSer: ProductsService,
   private salesSer: SalesService,
) {}
```

Now simply get data of all the three services and display it in your dashboard